# Full screen PDF with Preview on Monterey

Tags: preview, fullscreen, monterey

I have a presentation in PDF and I want it on full screen. How to get one?

When I use Preview full screen or slideshow I always get that black frame. I previously have had presentations in PowerPoint and there it works without any problems. What do I do now that I have a pdf?

How my screen looks like:

[image]

(I added the white box with black frame to hide the content of my slides, but that is not important, I want to know how to hide this thick black frame around it)

Comment: Can you add a screenshot so we see what you see? Also, what is the size of the screen, what is the ratio the presentation is using (4:3, 16:9)?

Comment: Done @nohillside

Comment: Is this a screenshot? What kind of preferences have you set? What happens if you zoom a bit in Preview?

Comment: Full screen, screenshot

Comment: What happens if you zoom in a bit within Preview. Does the black border disappear or does just the white part grow bigger?

Comment: Fullscreen doesn't necessarily expand to fit. Try Cmd/+

Comment: Ah, I get that frame as well when I run a slideshow from Preview (and Zoom doesn't work while a slideshow is running). So this seems to be a feature nowadays.

Comment: @nohillside yeah, but the thing is that i can't zoom each slide

Comment: @Tetsujin i can't zoom each slide

Comment: Hmm, yeah - works on Mojave, not on Big Sur. Can't eliminate the top & bottom bars.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a feature of Preview in Monterey.

You may want to use a 3rd party PDF viewer instead. I tried with [Skim](https://skim-app.sourceforge.io/), it uses the full screen in presentation mode.

Answer (score 0):

Full Screen should work for Preview in the same way as any other app. Obviously, the 'background' outside of the page will be dark, but if the PDF page is zoomed to match, then you won't see any black edge.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. When I use powerpoint I have slide over my whole screen and with Preview I have a black frame around it.